# Handle null in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2

There is a need where I want load data from local or remote. If local data fetched, remote data won't be fetched.

**As local data can be empty (i.e. null)**, I have to handle `null` situation in RxJava2, so I do it with help of `Optional` util in java-8. Here is code.

```
String data;

Observable<Optional<String>> loadCacheData() {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        emitter.onNext(Optional.ofNullable(null));
        emitter.onComplete();
    });
}

Observable<Optional<String>> loadRemoteData() {
    Observable<Optional<String>> remoteObservable = Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Optional<String>>) emitter -> {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        emitter.onNext(Optional.of("FromRemote"));
        emitter.onComplete();
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    remoteObservable.doOnNext(s -> data = s.get());

    return remoteObservable;
}

void fetchData() {
    Observable.concat(loadCacheData(), loadRemoteData())
            .filter(s -> s.isPresent())
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s.get()));
}
```

I want to know is there any other way to handle null in such situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you are trying to do is exactly what [Maybe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) provides: a source that can either have or not have data.

Here's an example of how I see this working:

```
public class MaybeExample {

    private final Network network;

    private String cachedData;

    public MaybeExample(final MaybeNetwork network) {
        this.network = network;
    }

    // Just used for the test... you'll probably have something smarter
    public void setCachedData(final String data) {
        cachedData = data;
    }

    private Maybe<String> loadCacheData() {
        return cachedData != null ? Maybe.just(cachedData) : Maybe.empty();
    }

    private Single<String> loadRemoteData() {
        return network.getData();
    }

    public Single<String> fetchData() {
        return loadCacheData().switchIfEmpty(loadRemoteData());
    }
}
```

And this would be a test to see it in action:

```
public class MaybeExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private Network network;

    private MaybeExample maybeExample;

    @Before
    public void createExample() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        maybeExample = new MaybeExample(network);
    }

    @Test
    public void nullCachedDataReturnsNetworkData() {
        maybeExample.setCachedData(null);
        final String networkValue = "FromNetwork";
        when(network.getData()).thenReturn(Single.just(networkValue));

        final TestObserver<String> observer = maybeExample.fetchData().test();

        observer.assertValue(networkValue);
    }

    @Test
    public void cachedDataIsReturnedWithoutCallingNetwork() {
        final String cachedValue = "FromCache";
        maybeExample.setCachedData(cachedValue);
        when(network.getData()).thenReturn(Single.error(new UnsupportedOperationException()));

        final TestObserver<String> observer = maybeExample.fetchData().test();

        observer.assertValue(cachedValue);
        observer.assertNoErrors();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't send `null` to `RxJava2` and **you shouldn't do that**, instead you can pass an empty list of your data.

`switchIfEmpty()` method can help you in both cases (network and local calls).

Comment: Why not a demo?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen in quite some projects the idea of returning static 'DEFAULT' object of given class. I don't feel much into this solution but it actually is other (and not so rare) way to handle null in RxJava.

It looks something like this:

```
class Anything(...) {
   companion object {
       val DEFAULT = Anything(...)
   }
}

Observable.fromCallable { getAnythingObject() }
            .onErrorReturn { Anything.DEFAULT }
```

And then checking:

```
    fun onReceived(anything: Anything) =
        when {
            anything === Anything.DEFAULT -> <TA DA!>
        }
```

Comment: Can you show code ? I can not understand your answer.

Comment: Your solution seems `Optional` while `Optional.ofNullable(null)`  is default object.

Comment: Well yes indeed. But doing stuff like this you have actual object so all casting, method calls etc is working normally. This is the main idea behind this