# RxJava2 Single.Concat for repository pattern

Tags: android, repository-pattern, rx-java2

I am using Room with RxJava2 to implement my data layer via Repository Pattern principles.

I have the following simple code which decides where to pick data from.

```
@Override
    public Single<Team> getTeamById(int teamId) {
        return Single.
                concat(local.getTeamById(teamId),
                        remote.getTeamById(teamId)).
                filter(team -> team != null).
                firstOrError();
    }
```

The problem here is that instead of going to the remote source , it returns an error from the first source (local) if the data was not available.

```
android.arch.persistence.room.EmptyResultSetException: Query returned empty result set: select * from teams where id = ?
```

How should I instruct the concat to forgo any error that is received and continue its concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue when the first source errors (instead of completing as empty), you can use `onErrorResumeNext` instead of `concat` (I assume both get calls return `Observable`, adjust as necessary):

```java
return local.getTeamById(teamId)
   .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
       if (error instanceof EmptyResultSetException) {
           return remote.getTeamById(teamId));
       }
       return Observable.error(error);
   })
   .firstOrError();
```

Comment: Please keep  in mind, that using onErrorResumeNext in this case is very inefficient. Handling exceptions in general is quite expensive and preventing an EmptyResultException is a nobrainer. Since Single will emit an error automatically  in case no item was emitted. I'd call this solution more than lazy and inefficient, as it adds complexity when there could not be any.

Comment: Well, it is Room that is creating and signalling an exception, before it gets into RxJava. If you can have Room not throw by using some other type, be my guest. Also I'm well aware of the performance characteristics of RxJava operators.

Comment: I'm really curious to know your reason for this choice, given you're one of the top contributors in RxJava here on SO. I have seen quite a handful of examples from seniors who use either `maybe` or `concat` for repository pattern

Comment: @Farid I don't understand your question. Please post a full SO question describing your case.

Comment: Rephrasing my question: I just wanted to know the reason you chose `onErrorResumeNext` over `concat`/`maybe` given that the majority of developers would either prefer `concat` or `maybe`. Considering that you're an active contributor of RxJava and I just wanted to know the reason. Hopefully, this was clear enough ))

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Concat is an operator that doesn't continue if a source signals error. Maybe is a type for expressing a source with no value, a single value or an error. I assume `local.getTeamById` can be declared with `Maybe` so that Room will not crash, in which case `concat(a, b).firstOrError()` would run `b` if `a` is empty or would not run `b` if `a` has value. The key here is that the OP had a case where a crash indicated a second source must be queried.

Answer (score 3):

Aslong you're not sure if you can receive at least one Team from you data provider, you should probably think of using Maybe instead of Single.

You can lookup the definition here:

[Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) as it states:

> it always either emits one value or an error notification

Use Maybe instead:
[Maybe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#maybe)

> there could be 0 or 1 item or an error signalled by some reactive
>   source

As your error already states there seems to be a problem while extracting results from your query.

Handle your result extraction correctly, so that you check if there are results before trying extracting any. Therefor the Maybe would either return 0 or 1 item, and not throw any error at all when no Team was found.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass null in RxJava2. So whenever your local repo is empty you just can't return null in your single. There was a question o stack about handling null objects: [Handle null in RxJava2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196095/handle-null-in-rxjava2/49196334#49196334)

Also here you can find an article showing you preferred implementation of repository pattern using RxJava2:
https://android.jlelse.eu/rxjava-2-single-concat-sample-for-repository-pattern-1873c456227a

So simplifying - instead of returning null from both local and remote repo pass some sort of "empty" object. That will be useful also in your business logic allowing you to recognize empty set of data.

Answer (score 1):

I used `Maybe` to solve my `Rxjava2` repository pattern problem.

In your case, I would use the following code to sort it out:

```
//you may need to rewrite your local.getTeamById method
protected Maybe<Team> getTeamById(int teamId) {
    Team team = localDataHelper.getTeamById(teamId);
    return team != null ? Maybe.just(team) : Maybe.empty();
}

@Override
public Single<Team> getTeamById(int teamId) {
    Maybe<Team> cacheObservable = local.getTeamById(teamId);
    Maybe<Team> apiCallObservable = remote.getTeamById(teamId).toMaybe();

    return Maybe.concat(cacheObservable, apiCallObservable)
            .toSingle();
}
```